# I just wrote "propriety" when I meant to say "proprietarity", but that's not a word. Does one exist?

Tags: single-word-requests

I just wrote the following [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/291854/#comment668893_291854):

> AFAIK there is virtually zero secrecy in commercial IC chips (except for those occasional little drop-ins for espionage). Aggressive deconstruction and reverse engineering abounds. **But there is certainly a lot of propriety** - so even of many people know, they may not want to write about it at length here in stackexchange.

As a user of English without a license, I've used the word "propriety" to try to refer to the treatment of intellectual property as proprietary. I wanted to use the term "proprpietarity" (lest I try to say  "proprietariness") but it did not appear to be a word. Have I mis-used propriety, and if so, is there a better word or short phrase that I could have used in its place?

While I have found words such as proprietarian, proprietariat, proprietarily, proprietary in an [ODO search for proprietarity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&query=proprietarity), I don't see a noun form that has the meaning I'm looking for.

Comment: To my surprise, I just learned that 'proprietary' has been used in law as a noun: https://dictionary.thelaw.com/proprietary-noun/. But I wouldn't recommend using it that way. :-)

Comment: It is still unclear what you really mean. Can you add a longer sentence without using words cognate to 'property' or 'propriety'?

Comment: Part of the problem lies in the contrast you have set up with *secrecy*.  You need to find established comparison/contrast pairwords that highlight the aspect you are compairing. Try *secrets* instead of *secrecy* in the first sentence. "AFAIK there are few well-kept secrets with respect to commercial IC chips (except for those occasional little drop-ins for espionage). Aggressive deconstruction and reverse engineering abounds. But there is certainly secrecy about reverse engineering efforts - so even if many people know, they may not want to write about it at length here in stackexchange."

Comment: @Mitch the comment by PhilSweet is getting closer to what I want to try to say. There are (at least) two ways in which intellectual property can be protected. One is to patent it, another is to keep it as proprietary information - known as a 'trade secret', sometimes loosely referred to as [special sauce](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/285155/102305). In the first, you protect information by publishing a carefully crafted description, in the second you avoid any disclosure except when it is legally a non-disclosure.

Comment: @Mitch If one thinks one has figured it out independently, one still might choose not to write publicly about it for various reasons. I'll keep thinking about this and see if I can further refine just what it is that I am trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Proprietarity* (or perhaps *proprietariacy*!) is technically well-formed, and certainly you are permitted to employ this kind of regular derivative without relying on previous use. But do you really want to loose such a monstrous genetic experiment on Great Mother English? Leave that to the lawyers and bureaucrats, and speak to your peers in our common language.

*Propriety* won't work: that got bracketed off from ownership at the beginning of the 18th century, and outside of a few fossilized legal contexts it's used today only in the sense "fitness" or "social correctness".

I suggest that you want to retreat another step beyond *propriety* to *property*, appropriately qualified:

> But there is certainly a lot of intellectual property, *or*
>    But there are certainly a lot of property rights

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I'm still hoping for a "-ness" type of word. I don't know what to call that kind of word exactly, but I don't want to say that there is a lot of intellectual property, but that there is a *lot of activity* in which IP is kept or withheld as proprietary information - the kind that is not disclosed in patents, and that one must demonstrate vigilance in not disclosing. I'm avoiding the word secrecy because it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: @uhoh How 'bout *proprietary reticence* :)

Comment: Such a kind word for behavior under the direction of corporate lawyers.

Comment: I just noticed I hadn't already accepted, sorry about that! I was surprised and happy to see that it can in some cases be ok to use a "regular derivative" without having seen it previously blessed. I do that with math equations all the time, but not for a moment thought I could do it with words. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you'll get is "proprietariness".

While I haven't yet found a dictionary that lists this form, it's common enough to show up on the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proprietariness%2C%20proprietarity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproprietariness%3B%2Cc0). Google search shows that it has some use in specialized fields; for example, "male (sexual) proprietariness" seems to be a term used in sociological/evopsych-related texts.

I believe the suffix *-ness* is by far the most productive way of forming a nominalization from an adjective. The suffix *-ity* is mostly only productive as part of what I'd call the "complex" suffix *[-ability](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/412318/77227)* (e.g. "lovability"). It also occurs in many words inherited from Latin or French, but there doesn't seem to be any Latin word "proprietaritas"<sup>1</sup>, and "proprietarité" seems to be as much of a neologism in French as it is in English<sup>2</sup>.

There are a few examples of *-ity* being used in English as a nominalizing suffix in other contexts, but it doesn't seem like a particularly obvious choice to me after an adjective ending in the suffix *-ary.* I couldn't think of any existing *-ary/-arity* pairs off the top of my head, and after looking it up, I was only found the following four examples of this pattern (roughly in order of most to least frequent, according to the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=complementarity%2Cbinarity%2Celementarity%2Csupplementarity&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomplementarity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbinarity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celementarity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csupplementarity%3B%2Cc0)):

1. complementarity (*from* complementary)
2. supplementarity (*from* supplementary)
3. binarity (*from* binary)
4. elementarity (*from* elementary)

Many *-ary* adjectives obviously do not allow this kind of derivation; e.g. *ordinary,* **ordinarity* (we use *ordinariness*); *voluntary,* **voluntarity* (we use *voluntariness*), *necessary,* **necessarity* (we use *necessity,* which does end in *-ity* but which is not built on top of the adjectival *-ary* suffix). There are a number of nominalizations ending in *-arity* built on adjectives in *-ar,* but that seems mostly irrelevant to me. (A further complication is that occasionally people have felt like using "-iety" instead; e.g. in *[subcontrariety](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subcontrariety)* from *subcontrary* and *[solitariety](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Solitariety)* from *solitary*.)

#### Possible rewording

As a side point, it seems to me that this particular sentence could be reworded to use adjectives, which I might recommend along the following lines:

> AFAIK there is virtually nothing that is secret in commercial IC chips (except for those occasional little drop-ins for espionage). Aggressive deconstruction and reverse engineering abounds. But there is certainly much that is proprietary - so even of many people know, they may not want to write about it at length here in stackexchange.

Some people might find the use of "much that is" a bit stuffy, but I don't think it sounds very bad.

### Side notes

#### 1. *Proprietaritas* looks fishy to me even as a possible neologism in Latin

I am by no means a Latin scholar, so if you want a reliable guide to Latin word formation you should ask someone trustworthy rather than reading the following paragraph. With that disclaimer aside, I'll just say that *it seems to me* that it is not just an accident that "*proprietaritas" is not a word in Latin; it looks like it would be an irregular formation. The adjective corresponding to *proprietary* in Latin is *proprietarius.* I can't find any example of a Latin adjective ending in *-ius* being nominalized by replacing *-ius* with the suffix *-itas;* the usual pattern seems to be instead *-ius* > *-ietas;* e.g. *notorius* > *notorietas.*

#### 2. Just for fun, the lone example of French "proprietarité" that I found

*I was able to find one example of "proprietarité" in a French forum message:

> Il me semble d'autre par que la proprietarité de leur matos peut poser probleme, mais je leur téléphone bientot pour confirmer ou infirmer totu ca. (Tix ; 18/07/2008 à 12h08, ["Cherche PC spécial", Futura Forums](http://forums.futura-sciences.com/materiel-hardware/236288-cherche-pc-special.html))

In French, the Latin suffixes *-aris* and *-arius* have in many cases become indistinguishable in form, both turning into *-aire* (e.g. French *polaire* from Latin *polaris,* *propriétaire* from *proprietarius*). So "proprietarité" as a French neologism seems likely to be to be formed by analogy with established word pairs like *polaire, polarité.*